# Simple GET request with ESP8266HTTPClient

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, iot

I am trying to do a simple GET request. But I always get status code -1. Here is my complete code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

WiFiClient client;
#define AP_SSID "CCR"
#define AP_PASSWORD  "ccrxxxxx"

void wifiConnect() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to AP");
  WiFi.begin(AP_SSID, AP_PASSWORD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(0,1);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(300);
  Serial.println("starting");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  Serial.println("disconnected");
  wifiConnect();
  Serial.println("Connected");
}

void loop() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("https://calm-falls-41696.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
  Serial.print("HTTP response code ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
  }
  http.end();
}
```

Wifi connection was successful. But in my serial terminal I always see -1. I am using PlatfromIO in Visual Studio code.

**Update 1:** The URL was corrected.

```
 http.begin("https://calm-falls-41696.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards.json");
```

I tested it with `google.com` too. But it is still returning -1.

Comment: Post your complete, working sketch so properly help you.

Comment: @LookAlterno I have posted my complete code.

Comment: I got an error in the linking phase. I have to check my environment. Working on it.

Comment: AFAIK, ESP8266HTTPClient doesn't support HTTPS. Also, why are you using a Content-Type header together with the GET method? That doesn't make any sense, because GET requests don't have a body.

Comment: I believe you need to supply the website certificate footprint to http.begin

Comment: Hi All,
i have a issue in http.post with timeout error.
I am getting data in chunks within 2 second from my device. I need to send that data to my web server. Example:
12 KB... then 1 sec wait.. then 12 KB data.. It's sending 2 separate files in this request, instead of maintaining connection and having 24 KB of file on web server. I am using httpclient for this and tried passing content-length as well. But doesn't work. Please guide / help / support.

Answer (score 4):

As Musa said, I needed to suply the website certificate footprint to http.begin.

```
void loop() {
  HTTPClient http;
  String thumbprint="08:3B:71:72:02:43:6E:CA:ED:42:86:93:BA:7E:DF:81:C4:BC:62:30";
  String path = "https://calm-falls-41696.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards.json";
  http.begin(path, thumbprint);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    Serial.print("HTTP response code ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
 }
  http.end();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code only changing the URL and header, like this:

```
//  http.begin("http://calm-falls-41696.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards");
  http.begin("http://bing.com");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

And it return httpCode == 400.

As @tttapa said, it looks like the library doesn't support https.